# How to make fields dinamically visible according parametrization in ASP.NET Web Forms?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, field, parameterized

I've an application which supports multiples companys, i.e., the user chooses which company he wants to view in the Login page.

After logged, depeding the company selected, the user can view a form with some fields.

Example:

- The user log in selecting the company ZZTOP.
- Then he navegates to the page Admin.aspx
- The page shows the fields User, Name, Address

...

- Another user log in selection the company BBC.
- Then he navegates to the page Admin.aspx
- The page shows de fields User, Name and AGE.

So I ask, what is the best way to make an application parameterized according to business rules, whereas some fields are allowed to be visible or not?

Comment: Place the Controls inside a `PlaceHolder` and set it's visibility.

Comment: But it is parameterized according to the company. So lets say I've 7 different companys, and each page "Admin.aspx" has one different control...I don't know what's the best way to do that...like put it in some json file?

Comment: Maybe `UserControls` is a better option.

Comment: @VDWWD thanks for answering. I don't think so, since my requeriment is that every field in every page must be flexible. Must I create a UserControl to every one?